# SQL - Concat full name, and a space only if last name is present

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation

I am currently concatenating a first and a last name like this (using PostgreSQL):

```
concat(customers.firstname, ' ', customers.lastname)
```

The problem I am having here is that I have customers that were entered with just a first name (ie. "Ronaldo"). The query above will return "Ronaldo " and that will not match.

I can use my server-side language to check for trailing spaces, but if there is a customer somewhere in my database that was accidentally typed in with a trailing space (ie. "Harry Potter "), then I won't match that one either.

I am looking for SQL that will return "Ronaldo", "John Smith", and "Harry Potter ". So basically I want to include a space between first and last name if last name is not equal to "" (empty string). If lastname is "" (empty string) then I want no space following the firstname. Is this possible with just SQL? Or will I have to figure out how to parse this appropriately with a server-side language?

Comment: can you not use a case statement instead? (I don't know the rest of your query):
`case when customers.lastname is null then customers.firstname else concat(customers.firstname, ' ', customers.lastname) end`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! Found the documentation too: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html.

Comment: You're welcome; You should post this as the accepted answer -- make a new answer and accept it.

Comment: @daf Simpler a bit: `concat(customers.firstname, ' ' || nullif(customers.lastname, ''))`

Comment: fair enough -- just be warned that this is postgre-specific syntax. I know the question is for postgre, but I personally try to avoid engine-specific syntax like the plague.

Answer (score 14):

You could use a [`TRIM()` function](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-trim-function/) call to strip off any leading or trailing spaces :

```
TRIM(CONCAT(customers.firstname, ' ', customers.lastname))
```

`TRIM()` also allows you to specific the characters you which to remove along with the location within the string (i.e. beginning, end, both, etc.) using the following syntax :

```
TRIM([LEADING | TRAILING | BOTH] [characters] FROM YourColumnOrString)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this trim the trailing space from "Harry Potter "?

Comment: Yes, it would, which should accomplish the same thing if you just had "Harry", as your `CONCAT()` would cause it to be "Harry " and then the trim would take care of the rest.

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
trim(both from COALESCE(firstname, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(lastname, '')
```

if both first and last name can be null.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
case
  when customers.lastname = ''
    then customers.firstname
  else
    concat(customers.firstname, ' ', customers.lastname)
end
```

Documentation for case: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html.

Special thanks to [daf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1697008/daf).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
This will remove all (start & end) the whitespaces

```
SELECT RTRIM(CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(First_Name)) , ' ' , LTRIM(RTRIM(Last_Name)))) 
AS 'Full_Name'
FROM tableName;
```

If you also want to insert middle name, you can try something like this...

```
SELECT (RTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(First_Name)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Middle_Name))) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Last_Name))) 
AS 'Full_Name'
FROM tableName;
```